# How to replace <<A1>> to «A1» in microsoft word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, mailmerge

In Microsoft word, I need to replace the word "<< A1 >>" to "«A1»". After the Find & Replace Process  that word is look like "A1". I don't know why. I need «A1» to apply mail Merge concept. Please Give your Suggestion and solution to get  «A1» from << A1 >>.

Comment: Not sure what mail Merge concept is, but depending on the text language you have set, "A1" is sometimes shown as «A1» (and vice-versa?)

Comment: Thanks. I am going to create a Document using Mail-merge. In my MsWord document , i have a word <<A1>>.  So I need to change <<A1>> as a Merge field like «A1», because then only i can apply mail-merge concept for  merge «A1»  field to my Datasource Value.

Comment: Kamal: Mail Merge field codes actually look like this: { MERGEFIELD A1 }, where the { } are special "field code braces" that you can enter using ctrl-F9 in Windows Word. When you insert such a field code, it either looks like { MERGEFIELD A1 }, or like «A1», or displays a data value. But just inserting «A1» won't give you a MailMerge field.

Answer (score 0):

- Using FIND and REPLACE, put << A1>> in the FIND WHAT box.
- copy «A1»  using Control-C  to put it in your clipboard.
- Then in the replace box enter:  ^c

That tells it to replace the << A1>> with whatever is in the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks blushRedTail. I Successfully replaced..Thanks to all